# ImportError: No module named torch in python

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I am trying to run my python file. I am running this command:

```
 python3 run.py --input_folder test_images/old_w_scratch --output_folder output --GPU 0 --with_scratch
```

But I get this error:

```
 Running Stage 1: Overall restoration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detection.py", line 12, in <module>
    import torch
ImportError: No module named torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    from torch.autograd import Variable
ImportError: No module named torch.autograd
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

when i install `torch`, it installs properly. But then when i run this, it doesn't work. Any chances someone could help me with it?

Comment: are you running torch in a conda or vitual env, if so your might not have it activated

Comment: @Kenan neither actually. I'm also on mac btw

Comment: I recommend using a conda environment `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch` check cuda

Comment: How did you install the `torch`?